# get the value from script content by using python

Tags: javascript, python, json, scrapy, load

[The source code of one page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbQt9.png)
I am writing a news sprider, and I want get the pubtime value from the script via python. Currently I can get the content of the script, it is like below:

```
{
        site:'sports',
        site_cname:'体育',
        site_url:'',
        title:'球爹喊话詹皇：想拿更多冠军 那就和我儿子搭档 ',
        id:'20170802002470',
        pubtime:'2017-08-02 06:22',
        type:'2',
        article_url:'',     
        sosokeys:{key1:'NBA',key2:'湖人',key3:'球爹',key4:'詹姆斯'},
        tags:['NBA','湖人','球爹','詹姆斯'],
        catalog:'basket',
        catalog_full:'sports-basket-nba',       
        sub_nav:'nba',      
        topic:{name:'',cname:'',ztcatalog:''},
        subName:{name:'basket',url:'', cname:'篮球'},
        isShowLastAD:'',
        tpl:
{dev:'nba',ver:'1.0.0.0',time:'20150512',type:'1',stype:''}
}
```

I have tried to use json.loads() method to transfer the string to json object, but it failed. It throws the error:

```
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes.
```

Before throwing this error, I have replaced all the " ' " with " . For this error, I know the reason may be all the keys should be enclosed in double quotes, but here are so many keys, and I think it is not the optimal choice to enclose every key with double quotes manually. Currently, I have no idea to handle the value of pubtime. Any suggestion is welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Share your code, not just the JSON and error.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools that parse json variables and such, primarily [`js2xml`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/js2xml), which is by the same guys who made scrapy.
However often simple regex is enough:

```
>>> text = "pubtime:'2017-08-02 06:22',"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("pubtime:'(.+?)'", text)
['2017-08-02 06:22']
```

In your case, of course, you'd use `response.body_as_unicode()` instead of predefined `text` variable to search the whole html body.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it with js2xml:

First, get the JavaScript code that you're interested in:

```
$ scrapy shell http://sports.qq.com/a/20170802/002470.htm
2017-08-04 18:41:23 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
2017-08-04 18:41:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://sports.qq.com/a/20170802/002470.htm> (referer: None)

>>> js = response.xpath('//script/text()').get()
>>> print(js)

        ARTICLE_INFO = window.ARTICLE_INFO || {
            site:'sports',
            site_cname:'体育',
            site_url:'http://sports.qq.com',
            title:'球爹喊话詹皇：想拿更多冠军 那就和我儿子搭档 ',
            id:'20170802002470',
            pubtime:'2017-08-02 06:22',
            type:'2',
            article_url:'http://sports.qq.com/a/20170802/002470.htm',       
            sosokeys:{key1:'NBA',key2:'湖人',key3:'球爹',key4:'詹姆斯'},
            tags:['NBA','湖人','球爹','詹姆斯'],
            catalog:'basket',
            catalog_full:'sports-basket-nba',       
            sub_nav:'nba',      
            topic:{name:'',cname:'',ztcatalog:''},
            subName:{name:'basket',url:'http://sports.qq.com/nba/', cname:'篮球'},
            isShowLastAD:'',
            tpl:{dev:'nba',ver:'1.0.0.0',time:'20150512',type:'1',stype:''}
            }
```

Then, feed this to `js2xml.parse()` to get a parse tree back:

```
>>> import js2xml
>>> tree = js2xml.parse(js)
```

You can check what js2xml parsed with `js2xml.pretty_print()`:

```
>>> print(js2xml.pretty_print(tree))
<program>
  <assign operator="=">
    <left>
      <identifier name="ARTICLE_INFO"/>
    </left>
    <right>
      <binaryoperation operation="||">
        <left>
          <dotaccessor>
            <object>
              <identifier name="window"/>
            </object>
            <property>
              <identifier name="ARTICLE_INFO"/>
            </property>
          </dotaccessor>
        </left>
        <right>
          <object>
            <property name="site">
              <string>sports</string>
            </property>
            <property name="site_cname">
              <string>体育</string>
            </property>
            <property name="site_url">
              <string>http://sports.qq.com</string>
            </property>
            <property name="title">
              <string>球爹喊话詹皇：想拿更多冠军 那就和我儿子搭档 </string>
            </property>
            <property name="id">
              <string>20170802002470</string>
            </property>
            <property name="pubtime">
              <string>2017-08-02 06:22</string>
            </property>
            <property name="type">
              <string>2</string>
            </property>
            <property name="article_url">
              <string>http://sports.qq.com/a/20170802/002470.htm</string>
            </property>
            <property name="sosokeys">
              <object>
                <property name="key1">
                  <string>NBA</string>
                </property>
                <property name="key2">
                  <string>湖人</string>
                </property>
                <property name="key3">
                  <string>球爹</string>
                </property>
                <property name="key4">
                  <string>詹姆斯</string>
                </property>
              </object>
            </property>
            <property name="tags">
              <array>
                <string>NBA</string>
                <string>湖人</string>
                <string>球爹</string>
                <string>詹姆斯</string>
              </array>
            </property>
            <property name="catalog">
              <string>basket</string>
            </property>
            <property name="catalog_full">
              <string>sports-basket-nba</string>
            </property>
            <property name="sub_nav">
              <string>nba</string>
            </property>
            <property name="topic">
              <object>
                <property name="name">
                  <string></string>
                </property>
                <property name="cname">
                  <string></string>
                </property>
                <property name="ztcatalog">
                  <string></string>
                </property>
              </object>
            </property>
            <property name="subName">
              <object>
                <property name="name">
                  <string>basket</string>
                </property>
                <property name="url">
                  <string>http://sports.qq.com/nba/</string>
                </property>
                <property name="cname">
                  <string>篮球</string>
                </property>
              </object>
            </property>
            <property name="isShowLastAD">
              <string></string>
            </property>
            <property name="tpl">
              <object>
                <property name="dev">
                  <string>nba</string>
                </property>
                <property name="ver">
                  <string>1.0.0.0</string>
                </property>
                <property name="time">
                  <string>20150512</string>
                </property>
                <property name="type">
                  <string>1</string>
                </property>
                <property name="stype">
                  <string></string>
                </property>
              </object>
            </property>
          </object>
        </right>
      </binaryoperation>
    </right>
  </assign>
</program>
```

The data you want is the `right` operand of the `||` binary operation. You can use XPath on the parse tree to get it:

```
>>> o = tree.xpath('//binaryoperation/right/object')[0]
>>> o
<Element object at 0x7f6c8c7967e8>
```

`js2xml.utils.objects.make` is used to build a Python object from this:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data)
{'article_url': 'http://sports.qq.com/a/20170802/002470.htm',
 'catalog': 'basket',
 'catalog_full': 'sports-basket-nba',
 'id': '20170802002470',
 'isShowLastAD': '',
 'pubtime': '2017-08-02 06:22',
 'site': 'sports',
 'site_cname': '体育',
 'site_url': 'http://sports.qq.com',
 'sosokeys': {'key1': 'NBA', 'key2': '湖人', 'key3': '球爹', 'key4': '詹姆斯'},
 'subName': {'cname': '篮球',
             'name': 'basket',
             'url': 'http://sports.qq.com/nba/'},
 'sub_nav': 'nba',
 'tags': ['NBA', '湖人', '球爹', '詹姆斯'],
 'title': '球爹喊话詹皇：想拿更多冠军 那就和我儿子搭档 ',
 'topic': {'cname': '', 'name': '', 'ztcatalog': ''},
 'tpl': {'dev': 'nba',
         'stype': '',
         'time': '20150512',
         'type': '1',
         'ver': '1.0.0.0'},
 'type': '2'}
>>>
```

As @Granitosaurus mentions, this can seem a bit "too much" for such a task, but it can prove useful when for example JSON data is not 100% JSON (using single quotes for example)